# Why explore Ceres?

Tags: mission-design, feasibility, dawn-mission, asteroid-belt, ceres

The multi-target orbiter Dawn spacecraft, launched in 2007, is now approaching the dwarf planet Ceres and had recently sent high resolution images of Ceres from a distance of 46,000 km.

[image: Ceres from 46,000km away, by DWAN spacecraft]

1. What is so interesting about Ceres that we decided to send a spacecraft to explore it?
2. Did the fact that Ceres is the largest body in the asteroid belt contribute to planning a mission to Ceres instead of other bodies? Perhaps being a more feasible target to orbit due to higher gravity?

Comment: For some of us, it was to figure out what the hell that white dot is: [xkcd.com/1476](http://xkcd.com/1476/)

Comment: @neelsg Go figure, but for one thing it seems to be two dots now.

Comment: All other things being equal (which they never are), I think a larger body is more likely to have something surprising to find on it.

Comment: @neelsg: Not to spoil the joke, but I thought Dawn *discovered* the white dot.

Comment: There's also the possilbity that it will answer this question: http://space.stackexchange.com/q/2738/8442

Comment: @KeithThompson ["The spot is visible from Earth, or at least from Earth’s orbit, showing up in photographs taken by the Hubble Space Telescope in 2003 and 2004"](http://www.iflscience.com/space/hopes-dawn-will-explain-white-spot-ceres). Dawn was launched in 2007

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Dawn has several mission objectives, including *to continue* testing the Ion Thruster.  But why Ceres?

Ceres and Vesta were chosen, because they have **contrasting content**, one icy and one rocky.  Also, they are among the [protoplanets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protoplanet) that **remain intact since formation**, which (hopefully) leads to a better understanding of the **formation of our solar system**, more specifically the different roles water and rock have.

We live in exciting times.

Comment: The Dawn mission objectives are all science objectives.  A previous mission, [DS-1](http://science.nasa.gov/missions/deep-space-1/), had the objective to prove out the ion propulsion technology.

Comment: Apologies - I can only cite wikipidea, which notes that Dawn is designed to "test the feasibility of its ion drive," - I should have phrased it better.  But thanks! I'm looking into DS-1 now, how cool!